# regular expression and unicode utf-8 in python?

Tags: python, regex, django, unicode

I have block of code:( Django code )

```
        list_temp = []
        tagname_re = re.compile(r'^[\w+\.-]+$', re.UNICODE)
        for key,tag in list.items():
            if len(tag) > settings.FORM_MAX_LENGTH_OF_TAG or len(tag) < settings.FORM_MIN_LENGTH_OF_TAG:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('please use between %(min)s and %(max)s characters in you tags') % { 'min': settings.FORM_MIN_LENGTH_OF_TAG, 'max': settings.FORM_MAX_LENGTH_OF_TAG})
            if not tagname_re.match(tag):
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('please use following characters in tags: letters , numbers, and characters \'.-_\''))
            # only keep one same tag
            if tag not in list_temp and len(tag.strip()) > 0:
                list_temp.append(tag)
```

This allow me to put the tag name in Unicode character.

But I don't know why with my Unicode (khmer uncode Khmer Symbols Range: 19E0–19FF The Unicode Standard, Version 4.0).I could not .

My question :

How can I change the above code`tagname_re = re.compile(r'^[\w+\.-]+$', re.UNICODE)` to adapt my Unicode character.?Because if I input the tag with the "នយោបាយ" I got the message?

`please use following characters in tags: letters , numbers, and characters \'.-_\''`

Comment: Remember that according to [The Unicode Standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties), the standard recommendation has `\w` matching all Alphabetics (which include more than just Letters), all Marks, all Decimal Numbers (digits), and all Connector Punctuation.

Comment: Try `\p{InKhmer}` or `\p{Khmer}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ោ (U+17C4 KHMER VOWEL SIGN OO) and ា (U+17B6 KHMER VOWEL SIGN AA) are not letters, they're combining marks, so they don't match \w.

Comment: Actually, U+17C4 and U+17B6 are *supposed* to match `\w` according to [the standards document, UTS#18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties). That’s because they have the `\p{Alphabetic}` property.  Compatibility with the Unicode Standard is why in Perl, they certainly **do** match `\w`, as is easily proven by running `perl -le 'print chr =~ /\w/ || 0 for 0x17BC, 0x17C4'` and noting the two 1 responses.

Comment: Encoding the string "នយោបាយ" using hex notation so there can be no shell trickiness, you’ll find that `perl -le '$str = "\x{1793}\x{1799}\x{17C4}\x{1794}\x{17B6}\x{1799}"; print length($1) if $str =~ /(\w+)/' ` correctly reports that group $1 matched 6 code points.  I thought Python’s `\w` conformed to the Unicode Standard when matching Unicode strings; does it not do so?

Comment: Interesting. UTS18, like the rest of Unicode, is an evolving standard. It would seem that TR18-7 is the first version of the document to mention `\b` being based on Alphabetic rather than the general character class (Mc); Python's Unicode regex implementation predates that.

Comment: Perl’s Unicode regex also predates that.  That doesn’t mean it’s held still. One endeavours to keep up with the Standard. The new properties are all supported (yes, all of them!), for example, and even named sequences. Besides the regex library and of course charnames, other things that track the Unicode standard include Unicode::Normalize, Unicode::Collate, Unicode::Collate::Locale, Unicode::GCString, and Unicode::LineBreak, all implementing various UTSs. The entire Unicode suite is really quite formidable; I don’t believe any other language does so much in its standard distro.

Answer (score 5):

[bobince's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441183/regular-expression-and-unicode-utf-8-in-python/5441295#5441295) is certainly correct.  However, before you hit that problem there might be another one - is `tag` definitely a `unicode` rather than a `str`?  For example:

```
>>> str_version = 'នយោបាយ'
>>> type(str_version)
<type 'str'>
>>> print str_version
នយោបាយ
>>> unicode_version = 'នយោបាយ'.decode('utf-8')
>>> type(unicode_version)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print unicode_version
នយោបាយ
>>> r = re.compile(r'^(\w+)',re.U)
>>> r.search(str_version).group(1)
'\xe1'
>>> print r.search(str_version).group(1)

>>> r.search(unicode_version).group(1)
u'\1793\u1799'
>>> print r.search(unicode_version).group(1)
នយ
```

As another small point, in your regular expression the `+` in the character class just means that a literal `+` is also allowed in the sequence of letters and punctuation.

Comment: That looks like django code and if it is, it's a 99.9% that it is a unicode string (django lives on unicode). if it is type str then there is a couple of helpers to convert it in django.utils.encoding smart_unicode and force_unicode.  The big difference is smart doesn't resolve lazy objects right away.

Comment: Good point - I wasn't paying attention to the context. Still, this might be useful for someone searching for something similar, so I'll leave it  undeleted...

Comment: what version of python you use in this demonstration.

Comment: @IEnAK: That was Python 2.6.6

Comment: There is no such thing called `django code`, That is `python`.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [new regex implementation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) on PyPI:

```
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex
```

With Python 3 it says:

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.match("\w", "\u17C4")
<_regex.Match object at 0x00F03988>
>>> regex.match("\w", "\u17B6")
<_regex.Match object at 0x00F03D08>
```